# Java Mail Error: 550 SMTP authentication

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I had the following error regarding the java  SSL certificate for sending email:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 23 more
```

I have generated a certificate using InstallCert.java and NOW i am getting the following error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 SMTP authentication mandatory

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
at com.MailerPecUtility.sendMail(MailerPecUtility.java:201)
at com.MailerPecUtility.main(MailerPecUtility.java:266)
```

Anyone knows how should i resolve this ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth), you need to authenticate to your server.  In addition to the example in the FAQ, you can use the [Transport.send method that takes a username and password](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
 transport.connect(specProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), port, user, pass);
```

I had to use this:

```
 transport.connect( null,smtpUser,smtpPassword);
```

Therefore, by the following way, I could send the email without error:

```
         message.setText("The email body text");
         Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
         transport.connect( null,smtpUser,smtpPassword);
         message.saveChanges();
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Message Has been sent!");
```